# React.Children does not display children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to use [react-native-maps-clustering](https://github.com/venits/react-native-map-clustering) but this one only takes markers which are direct children of maps.

like the example

```
<MapView>
  <Marker/>
  <Marker/>
</MapView>
```

In my case my markers are in another file nested in other elements

```
<MapView>
  <MarkersLayer/>
</MapView>
```

**MarkersLayer.tsx**

```
<Fragment>
  <Trajectory/>
 <Fragment>
  <Marker>
     <MarkerStyle/>
  <Marker/>
 </Fragment>
</Fragment>
```

*Test : In the library - ClusteredMapView.js - l.84*

```
      propsChildren.forEach((child, index) => {
        //my test
        if (child.type?.name == "MarkersLayer"){
          console.log('I am MarkersLayer')
          React.Children.forEach(child, ch => {
            console.log("child MarkersLayer", ch)
          })
        }else if (child.props.coordinate){
          console.log("I am a marker", child)
        }
         //end
        if (isMarker(child)) {
          rawData.push(markerToGeoJSONFeature(child, index));
        } else {
          otherChildren.push(child);
        }
      });
```

Children in MapView :

[image]

Children in MarkerLayer :

[image]

*Test : In my MarkerLayer component*

```
  const propsChildren = useMemo(
    () => React.Children.toArray(children),
    [children],
  );
```

Result :

[image]

The library uses React.Children to find the children contained in MapView but I can't get the markers in MarkerLayer.

Thanks for the people reading this post and for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useState()` and `useEffect()`.

This is done like so:

```js
const [children, setChildren] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setChildren(React.Children.toArray(children))
}, []);
```